# Pandas convert dataframe values to column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to use dataframe values as column names and simplify the dataframe.

I tried `df.stack()` and then `index.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format)`

Input_df(Got this df by doing a groupby):

```
link price  date
 A     1    01/01
 A     2    01/02
 A     1.2  01/03
```

Desired_ouput:

```
link price_01/01 price_01/02 price_01/03
  A      1            2         1.2
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Forget mapping over a multiindex

```
df.set_index(['link', 'date']).price.unstack().add_prefix('price_')

date  price_01/01  price_01/02  price_01/03
link                                       
A             1.0          2.0          1.2
```

Comment: I think this is extremely wise too.  +1

Comment: @piRSquared: This is great. Scott Botton's answer is traditional one. Yours is new and very creative! I gave both you and scott +1.

Comment: Probably known already, but you can tack `.fillna(0)` on the end of this if you're not repeating all the category vals in every row in the newly created set.  The above code (which works well!) left me with a lot of NaN in my resultant rows at first.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this using `set_index` and `unstack`, then using Python 3.6+ can you use f-string with list comprehension to flatten multiindex column headers.

```
df_out = df.set_index(['link', 'date']).unstack()

df_out.columns = [f'{i}_{j}' for i, j in df_out.columns]

df_out.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  link  price_01/01  price_01/02  price_01/03
0    A          1.0          2.0          1.2
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

You can `pivot` your table:

```
df['date'] = 'price_' + df['date']
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df = df.pivot(index='link', columns='date', values='price')

print(df)
```

Output:

```
date  price_01/01  price_01/02  price_01/03
link                                       
A             1.0          2.0          1.2
```