# Dataframe convert value in columns into colums name

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, transpose

I would like to convert the name value in columns Name into Name columns and convert the rest value in one rows. I try to use Pivot, but is not working very well for my problem.

Do you have some idea ?

Input :

```
dict_value = {
'Name' : ['Pierre', 'Paul'],
'Age' : [10,20],
'City' : ['NY', 'PR']}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict_value)
```

[image]

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`df.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) then flatten the `MultiIndex`. Then use [`.to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and transpose.

```
out = df.set_index('Name').stack()
out.index = out.index.map('.'.join)
out.to_frame().T

  Pierre.Age Pierre.City Paul.Age Paul.City
0         10          NY       20        PR
```

Comment: @FloCp Glad to help. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I believe by using *set_index* and *unstack* you might get the solution you want. You could check  [Pandas convert dataframe values to column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56064617/pandas-convert-dataframe-values-to-column-names)